# Enable federation to Youtube data api

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a scenario where user of my application has to upload videos to my youtube playlist. To achieve this I was thinking to enable federation (if available from google/youtube) between my app and youtube.

1) User logs in to my app and obtains a token issued by my app
2) User upload video with the token
3) Youtube honors the token as issuer of the token is federated

So the open question is if youtube has a federation mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your account info on the server, then have **your own authentication** per user to check them. Then your online code will use **your** token's to upload.

That will be as if you are the uploader. But you will need to keep that info secure. But can be done.